# Release non-cmake 3rd party libraries with bloom

Tags: ros, bloom-release, third-party, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to release [gflags](https://code.google.com/p/gflags/) with bloom (my final goal is to make the buildfarm create debians for [ceres-solver](https://code.google.com/p/ceres-solver/)). Unfortunately the port from automake to cmake for gflags is not finished yet.

That's why I want to know if it is possible to make the buildfarm create debians for source code that compiles with `./configure && make && make install` instead of cmake.
Is there a special `build_type` for automake that I can use in my `package.xml`?

If this is not possible, should I inject a simple CMakeLists.txt that calls [ExternalProject_Add](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63972/release-non-cmake-3rd-party-libraries-with-bloom/) by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1924 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have only implemented build_type cmake and the default one catkin.  It was designed to be extended to build autotools.  It looks like there are some [stubs](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/blob/master/bloom/generators/debian/templates/rules.autotools.em) there, but I am not aware of any package actively using it yet.

@William can give more insight when he gets back from vacation.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-30**:
You can extend catkin to support autotools, or you can just wrap the autotools up in a simple CMakeLists.txt. I can provide a better answer later.

**Comment by [Frantisek.Durovsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/19768/frantisek.durovsky/) on 2015-12-20**:
Hi guys, I m facing the same problem with releasing non-cmake library into ROS ecosystem. I have red bloom tutorial but I dont understand how to adopt it for library compiled by make && make install. What is recommended procedure now at the end of 2015? Is there any example available? Thanks

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-20**:
I'd still recommend wrapping up the non-cmake library you want in a `CMakeLists.txt`. I don't know of a good example of this off hand, maybe someone else on this site can link you one.